# Is $L = \{\omega : \omega\text{ contains exactly one 'foobar'}\}$ regular?

Tags: regular-language

Is the language $L = \{\omega : \omega\text{ contains exactly one 'foobar'}\}$ regular? I have a hunch that it is non-regular because a regular expression representing the language must remember that is has encountered the substring 'foobar.'

However, I can't seem to use the pumping lemma to prove that it is indeed not regular. Say $s \in L$ and $s$ is of the form

```
[substring not containing 'foobar']foobar[substring not containing 'foobar'].
```

Then, $L$ is pumpable because $s = xyz \in L$ for $|s| > p$, where $y$ can be a substring within either section labeled `[substring not containing 'foobar']`. If we repeat $y$ $j$ times, $xy^jz$ will still be in $L$.

However, again, $L$ doesn't seem regular to me... why is my pumping lemma proof erring?

Comment: $L$ is in fact regular; it's probably easier to see this by finding a finite-state machine that accepts $L$ than a regular expression.

Comment: It's regular because the FSM can count the number of `foobar` that it sees, and it never has to count higher than 2 to know the answer.

Comment: @MJD: Saying a "FSM can count the number of `foobar` that it sees" might be a bit misleading to the question at hand.  Perhaps it is better to say that similar to some (caricatures of) primitive tribes, DFAs can count the number of occurrences of `foobar` as 0, 1, 2, 3, $\ldots$ , $n-1$, many.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, saying "...it never has to count higher than 2" is crucial, which is why I said that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** It is regular. So one cannot expect the Pumping Lemma to yield anything.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here’s a regular grammar that generates the language in question. The $S$ and $A_k$ productions generate the first part of the string, the $B$ productions generate the `foobar`, and the $R$ and $C_k$ productions generate the last part of the string.

Let $\bar f$ represent any terminal character other than $f$, $\bar o$ any terminal character other than $o$, and so on, and let $x$ represent any terminal character.

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to fA_1\mid \bar fS\mid fB_2\mid B_1\\
&A_1\to oA_2\mid\bar oS\\
&A_2\to oA_3\mid\bar oS\\
&A_3\to bA_4\mid\bar bS\\
&A_4\to aA_5\mid\bar aS\\
&A_5\to\bar rS\\
&B_1\to fB_2\\
&B_2\to oB_3\\
&B_3\to oB_4\\
&B_4\to bB_5\\
&B_5\to aB_6\\
&B_6\to rR\mid r\\
&R\to fC_1\mid\bar fR\mid x\\
&C_1\to oC_2\mid\bar oR\mid x\\
&C_2\to oC_3\mid\bar oR\mid x\\
&C_3\to bC_4\mid\bar bR\mid x\\
&C_4\to aC_5\mid\bar aR\mid x\\
&C_5\to \bar rR\mid\bar r
\end{align*}$$